Write only Nginx WebDAV configuration
I want to create a write only WebDAV location / feature for Nginx. Currently I have the following configuration file (relevant part only).
 location ~ "/webdav/([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*)$" {
  alias  /storage/www/webdav/$1;
  client_body_temp_path /tmp/upl_tmp;
  dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
  create_full_put_path on;
  dav_access    group:rw all:r;
}

If someone wants to upload a file they can through curl.exe -T foo.txt https://webserver.com/webdav/foo.txt. This will be stored in the /storage/www/webdav directory, outside of the typical webroot (/var/www/html).
The problem (for me) is they can still access it at https://webserver.com/webdav/foo.txt after the upload. I want a write only configuration, so the behavior is the same, but the user cannot access the file after uploading.
I've attempted to modify the dav_access permissions, but Nginx seems to thing that only having write permissions (no read) is invalid.
Any idea on how I can achieve this?
Thanks.

I ended up getting this working by putting a limit on the other methods that would be used to retrieve the file.
 location ~ "/webdav/([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*)$" {
  alias  /storage/www/webdav/$1;
  client_body_temp_path /tmp/upl_tmp;
  dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
  create_full_put_path on;
  dav_access    group:rw all:r;
  
  limit_except PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE {
          deny all;
  }
}

Now when someone attempts to retrieve the file (via for example, a GET request) it returns a 403.
